# jQuery detach() and remove() both not working on appended element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a body on click function that conditionally adds or removes a button.

The adding works, but neither `remove()` nor `detach()` works.

I am rotating an image and I only want to show a "Save" button when the image is rotated from the original.

This is all inside document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var $save = $('<div id="savebutton_container"><button name="savebutton" id="savebutton">Save</button></div>');

        $('body').on('click','img',function() {
            if(typeof rotate.counter == 'undefined') {
                rotate.counter = 0;
            }   
            rotate.counter += 90;
            if(rotate.counter === 360) {
                rotate.counter = 0;
            }
            console.log(rotate.counter);
            $(this).removeClass(function(index,css){ // clear classes first.
                return (css.match (/(^|\s)rotate\S+/g) || []).join(' '); // remove rotational classes
            });

            if(!(rotate.counter == 0) ) { // NOT 0 degrees
                console.log('rotate counter is not 0');
                $(this).addClass('rotate' + rotate.counter); // rotate the image
                if( $("#savebutton_container").length === 0 ) { // WORKS!
                    $(this).parents().append($save); // global $save
                }
            } else {
                console.log('rotate counter is 0');
                $("#savebutton_container").detach(); // works seemingly randomly
               // Also tried $save.detach();// also tried .remove();

            }

    });
});
```

Every once in a while the save button will disappear. The console ALWAYS logs the "rotate counter is 0" whenever it is supposed to, but the save button does not go away!

Comment: Have you tried `$save.remove()`?

Comment: What happens when you do `console.log($("[id='savebutton_container']").length);` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from your usage of `parents()` instead of `parent()` in the line

```
$(this).parents().append($save);
```

The `parents()` method returns all ancestor elements from the selection, traversing up, while `parent()` returns only the first parent.

You are retrieving all `parents()` of the image (e.g. `<body>`, `<html>`, etc.) and appending `$save` to all of them. Using `append(elem)` on a multi-element selection results `elem` being cloned and appended to every target in the selection. This is not what you want, and this is causing you to lose the `$save` reference (especially since you are appending multiple copies of an element with the same `id`).

This [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KBvSSQtbhsmdejxuCj58?p=preview) has a slightly simplified working version of what you want (click on the image to test). Note that `detach()` is correct, `remove()` is not. `detach()` preserves all jQuery metadata about the element, it is specifically used when you plan to re-attach the element later. `remove()` is used when you want to discard the element.

Comment: You are right about parents / vs parent. Funny thing is I used `parent()` first but something wasn't working and when I googled "jquery parent", Google showed me the snippet for "parents" and I thought I had mis-remembered the function name. Now everything is working. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I had my chrome console taking up half the page and didn't see 2-3 other save buttons popping up around the page. And yes I do want `detach()`, since I am going to be reusing that button. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use `$(document).on('click'...)` instead of `$(body).on()`

Since the element that you have created is dynamically created you need to recheck the dom starting from the root of the dom tree.

Whenever I am using dynamic elements I always make sure that my event triggers are running off of my `$(document)` selector.

Comment: That seems like a good thing to do. I will change that as well. Thank you.